# Is it possible to construct Hausdorff compact topology on every set?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'd like to know if it's possible to construct Hausdorff compact topology on every set. Assume the axiom of choice if needed.
Thanks for ideas.

Comment: For any infinite set $X$, consider the one-point compactification of the discrete topology of $X$.

Comment: @Crostul Same as Brian's topology below, right?

Comment: @ForeverMozart Yes, this is the same topology.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Let $X$ be any non-empty set. Perhaps the easiest way is to fix a point $p\in X$, let $Y=X\setminus\{p\}$, and set

$$\tau=\wp(Y)\cup\{X\setminus F:F\subseteq Y\text{ and }F\text{ is finite}\}\;.$$

Then $\tau$ is a compact Hausdorff topology on $X$. It’s easy to check that it’s Hausdorff. If $\mathscr{U}$ is any open cover of $X$, there is a $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ containing $p$, and $X\setminus U_0$ is finite and therefore covered by just finitely many more members of $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: what does that symbol mean?

Comment: Is that power set of $Y$?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: Yes. It’s non-standard, but I’ve always used it, because it looks more like my handwritten power set symbol than any of the other available choices.

Comment: @Brian: Maybe it's time to work on your penmanship, then! :-)

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Comment: @Asaf: My penmanship is actually rather good, or at any rate was before age and constant typing got to it, but it’s italics, and the upper-case P is somewhere between $P$ and $\mathcal{P}$. I deliberately use something different for power set. (And my calligraphic upper-case P’s depend on the hand and are different yet!)

Comment: Note that $Y$ is discrete and $X$ is its one-point compactification (if $Y$ is infinite).